# Programmatically connecting to a specific wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

I would like to connect to specific wifi programmatically in android. I referred lot of links. But still not yet achieve the goal. I am following below code to connect specific wifi.

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  WifiConfiguration configuration = new WifiConfiguration();
                                    configuration.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", "ssid");
                                    configuration.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", "paasword");
                                    configuration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                                    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(configuration);
                                    wifiManager.disconnect();
                                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId,true);
                                    wifiManager.reconnect();
```

When I was try to run this code stuff.. wifi connection will be disconnected and again automatically connected previous wifi network.I am using redmi 6a mobile(version 9) for testing purpose.
Can any one guide me how to resolve this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to loop through all available networks, then connect to right one if it is available.

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         wifiManager.reconnect();               

         break;
    }else{Log.e("TAG","Network Not Available")}           
}
```

Comment: After looping its working fine. Thanks you save my day.

Comment: can you accept the answer if this answer solved your problem :)